# Filter Excel data when importing into Visio OrgChart

Tags: excel, visio, orgchart

In Visio I am creating an Org Chart, using the 'Import Organization Data', and using 'Information that's already stored in a file or database'. When I select my xlsx file, it pulls in all of the data. However, what if I wanted to only create an org chart out of a subset of the data? Currently I'm applying a filter to the data in Excel, copying the result to a new Excel file, and using that new file to import into Visio. A slightly less bad version of this would be if I could at least copy the filtered data into a different sheet in the same file, but the Visio Import doesn't even seem to let me select which sheet to use. This is very annoying - is there a better way?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but it should work. Don't use your primary excel table as dataset for visio, but a second one, built using power query inside excel.

Comment: @y4cine but how do you choose the dataset? The only thing I see how to choose from Visio is the Excel file.

Comment: After having chosen the Excel file, you're asked to choose a sheet or a table. That's where you choose the 2nd table.

Comment: @y4cine That would make a ton of sense, but unfortunately I am not asked to choose such a thing. I am on Visio Professional latest version (365 or whatever it's called these days

Comment: I set up a working proof of concept here: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9923.msg45406;topicseen#msg45406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I could never get Visio to ask me which table/sheet I wanted to use within a single file, I found what I consider an acceptable workaround using inspiration from @y4cine's suggestion.

I created separate "slice" xlsx files, where in each of those I used a Power Query against the data in the main xlsx file. Then I can point Visio to one of those slice files and it will happily make an org chart with the slice of data I was interested in.

A bit clunky, but it sure beats repeated copy/pasting :)